# Function creation failed because the function already exists - Creating Lambda function through serverless.yml Github Action

Tags: aws-lambda, github-actions, serverless, aws-sam

How I can override/replace the existing Lambda Function which already exists?

> Maybe I have to pass some parameters in my serverless.yml file to
> replace my existing lambda function while creating with the same name!

getting error

```
Error:
× Stack example-dev failed to deploy (66s)
CREATE_FAILED: exampleLambdaFunction (AWS::Lambda::Function)
Environment: linux, node 18.17.1, framework 3.36.0, plugin 7.1.0, SDK 4.4.0
Resource handler returned message: "Function creation failed because the function already exists" (RequestToken: f6a821ae-279c-3a1b-eac8-9d29f61ae3bf, HandlerErrorCode: AlreadyExists)
Credentials: Local, environment variables
```

my serverless.yml file

```
service: example

frameworkVersion: "3"

provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: nodejs14.x

# you can overwrite defaults here
  stage: dev
  region: ap-south-1

  versionFunctions: false

# you can define service wide environment variables here
  environment:
    TZ: Asia/Kolkata


functions:
  example:
    handler: index.handler
    name: example
```

Answer (score 0):

You can automate your lambda function deployment using github actions. [You can check this article](https://medium.com/@ivangomezarnedo/automating-aws-lambda-deployments-with-github-actions-cc632138d069)

Comment: I hope this article will answer your question